# How can i timeout a response depending on your role?

Tags: javascript, timeout, discord, discord.js, roles

i want my bot to wait a certain amount of time before it answers depending on your role but it doesn't work and i don't know how to do it, can anyone help me please?

```js
//cd test
client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${PREFIX}rpg hunts`)) {
        let user = msg.mentions.roles.first();
let time;
switch (role) {
  case '733786365342253087': time = 60000; break;
  case '733786293435105422': time = 54000; break;
  case '733786784336445461': time = 48000; break;
  case '733786616769937439': time = 39000; break;
}
setTimeout(() => {
            msg.channel.send(`Your **RPG HUNT** is ready! <@${msg.author.id}>`);
},time)
    }
});
//cd test
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var time;
switch ('4') {
  case '1': time = 1000; break;
  case '2': time = 2000; break;
  case '3': time = 3000; break;
  case '4': time = 5000; break;
}
console.log('time now', new Date().getTime());
setTimeout(() => {
console.log('posting at', new Date().getTime());
}, time);
```

The code looks good. But one of the possible errors might be in typeof role.
Make sure it is string. Not number.

```
role should be '111111' 
should not be 111111
```

Console log and check 'role'. Make sure you are using correct variable. Looks like role is not declared at all. You have used let 'user'